# What's a 'pervasive database'?

Tags: database, definition, pervasive

I'm sorry, but this keyword doesn't mean anything to me... Can someone give me a definition?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a brand.  [http://pervasive.com/](http://www.pervasive.com/) And here is a link to their DB products http://www.pervasivedb.com/Pages/PDBProducts.aspx including Pervasive PSQL

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [Pervasive PSQL](http://ww2.pervasive.com/Database/Products/PSQLv10/Pages/PSQLOverview.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

[eDeveloper](http://www.magicsoftware.com/) and previous versions of Magic (4GL) use this database as default.